# What's the proper way to setup a TypeScript package that will be a private module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, package.json

In my `package.json`, I have:

```
{
    "name": "@myapp/models",
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "description": "My Models",
    "license": "ISC",
    "main": "build/index.js",
    "types": "build/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "yarn build",
        "build": "yarn cache clean && tsc"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/shamoons/mymodels"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "pg": "^8.2.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "sequelize": "^5.21.12",
        "sequelize-typescript": "^1.1.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.32",
        "@types/node": "^14.0.13",
        "@types/validator": "^13.0.0",
        "typescript": "^3.9.5"
    }
}
```

But when I `npm install` this into another repo, I get:

```
/bin/sh: tsc: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the postinstall npm script, which runs after you install the package.

Comment: But why is tsc not found?

Comment: Because it's defined in `devDependencies`. When you `npm install` a package, only the `dependencies` are installed. If you actually want to build the extension after installation, move `typescript` into `dependencies`.